# Spring Web Flow: How to call static method from <evaluate />?

Tags: java, spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

I need to call static method of [org.hibernate.Hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html) class.
How to do that in  element of flow ?

Comment: Can you elaborate more in detail?

Comment: @Mohamed Saligh: More details - I have Product entity with list of images, that are lazy initialized. In a flow (on entry some view) i need to initialize images by calling org.hibernate.Hibernate.initialize() static method. How to do that ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the following Spring EL construct to evaluate static methods:

```
<evaluate expression="T(org.hibernate.Hibernate).initialize(yourObject)"/>
```

See the appropriate Spring EL reference part:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-types

Answer (score 0):

spring-webflow 2 uses OGNL expressions.  OGNL allows for static referencing of fields and methods.  To utilize it you would want to use the '@' notations.

First you reference the class (with package).  You would want to put an @ before the package and class name and an @ before the method call.  With hibernate it would look like

```
<evaluate expression="@org.hibernate.Hibernate@initialize()"/>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I get parse error: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E:(pos 24): After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'bean_ref(@)'