# Parsing Spring EL Variable in View

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I have an variable written in Spring EL that I want to url decode, can I just drop in a piece of code between the curly brackets or does the parsing have to be done in the controller?

```
<form:hidden id="pass" path="password" value="${param.password}" htmlEscape="true" />
```

For example, can I do something like this:

```
<form:hidden id="pass" path="password" value="${URLDecoder.decode(param.password, "UTF-8")}" htmlEscape="true" />
```

The issue is that some passwords have special characters and are url encoded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `spring:eval` to execute the static method call and set the value. References:

[Spring Eval Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/spring.tld.html#spring.tld.eval)

[Spring Eval Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254982/spring-web-flow-how-to-call-static-method-from-evaluate)

**Update:**

[Spring Eval Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21581323/584420)

**Update**:
Tried with what you were looking for and here is what I have:

**Controller**:

```
@RequestMapping("/testStaticCall")
    public String testStaticCall(ModelMap map) {
        map.addAttribute("password", "1234%23");
        return "testStaticCallJsp";
    }
```

**JSP**:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8" isELIgnored="false" %>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <spring:eval expression="T(java.net.URLDecoder).decode(password)" var="decodedPassword"></spring:eval>
    <form:input id="pass" path="password" value="${decodedPassword}" htmlEscape="true" />
</body>
</html>
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Something like this? `<spring:eval expression="T(java.net.URLDecoder).decode(param.password)" var="decodedPassword"></spring:eval>` and then use `decodedPassword` as the new value?

Comment: Nope, doesn't seem to decoding non-alpha numeric characters.

Comment: Could you please compare the return value at controller side with what is generated? Just mentioned a way to call static method.

Comment: Are you referring to HTTP URL decode something like thishttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750290/how-to-decode-html-codes-using-java

Comment: The password is along the lines of `1234%23` which should be `1234#`.